# Cmake and multi stage build pipelines (reuse)

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cpp cmake project that takes a bit to compile the core components.

Let's say

- Component A (Takes 2 hours to compile)
- Component B (Takes 1 hour to compile)
- Component C needs to statically link in Component A and B (takes 5 minutes)

We mostly are only changing Component C.

But we want our PR Build gates to rebuild A and B if they have to, but not necessarily if there wasn't any changes.

I'd like to build component A and B once per night.

Then during the day, allow our PR gates to download the intermediates from them, and then do an incremental build, only rebuilding the parts that have changed.

However, cmake seems to embed a lot of folder path information into the intermediates/ cache stamp files and stuff.  And our build machines have slightly different paths each time. (e.g. c:\repo###\sourceDir\
and the ### changes each time.

Is there any easy way to do this? Or do I have to 'modify all the relevant .txt, .tlog, cache text, etc.. files'  and also manipulate the timestamps back to their originals after modifying the files path to match the current machine.

I tried just copying over the /intermediates/ folder with all the .obj and other things, but I think cmake is picky about the folderpaths.

And I don't want to consume the prebuilt .lib or .dll from component A or B, because we might have made a change to them, so it should do incremental in that case.

Edit/answers

I haven't looked into ccache yet, hadn't heard of it.

we evoke it via cmake.exe (configure/build/install) cmakelists.txt. Each component does have their own cmakelists.txt in a toplevelfolder

- src/componentA/cmakelists.txt (controls everything in itself, has no ledge of B or C)
- src/componentA/cmakelists.txt (controls everything in itself, has no ledge of A or C)
- src/componentC/cmakelists.txt (controls everything in itself + include from A and B)

Comment: did you thought of using `ccache`?

Comment: How is cmake involved here? Are you using tree-like cmake structure with A B and C being subfolder cmakelisted in top level folder cmakelist?

Comment: I will look into ccache, not familiar with it.

Comment: edited main comment.

Comment: CMake "intermediates" (artifacts produced at configuration and build stage) are not intended to be moved into another machine. Unless that another machine is very very "similar" to the one where these intermediates are produced, with the same utilities and their paths, same source and build directories and so.

Comment: @Tsyvarev how 'similar' do you mean?  Most of our build machines generally have the same version of things.  There might be a few that have slightly different versions.    If it's not compatible, will it break or just rebuild the bits?

Comment: "If it's not compatible, will it break or just rebuild the bits?" - As far as I know, CMake doesn't "watch" for the timestamps and exact content of the tools (like compiler). So it will assume that your have **the same** tool, and wouldn't rebuild anything.